# Short story: End line "he was a coward"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This would be an old science fiction short story, probably 90's or before... possibly decently before. It tells of a prince (or equivelant) who, before he can be confirmed as a prince, has to undergo a test on some primitive planet, or a primitive area of their planet. He has a servant or someone who goes with him for the test.
The boy ends up dying on the test, or otherwise failing, and the servant, when he comes back to the king, is forced to say 'he was a coward'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54996/fantasy-short-story-that-appeared-in-an-anthology-about-1968-1971 -- the accepted answer was "Call Him Lord" by Gordon R. Dickson.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.